# Error: "Frame substitution recur..." while importing insta360 pro II video files post insta360 stitcher. Fixes have not helped

Tags: import, large-files, virtual-reality, adobe-premiere

First, here is my setup:

Rig:

- Windows 10
- AMD Ryzen ThreadRipper 3970x 32-core Processor (64 CPUs)
- Nvidia GeForce RTX 3080 Ti
- 125 GB Ram
- New installation of Premiere pro 2021 with updated importer files as requested [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Insta360/comments/mr02s0/help_error_on_import_into_premiere_pro_2021/) and downloaded [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1WWEPKVCus2RNopAQeaZqJCoKS0t4mGjI)

When I import a video file that has already been processed in insta360 stitcher, and that look like this:

[image: Example a file that I am trying to import, this is what is requested, and it does properly import the file after updating the files]

I start getting this error while premiere is trying to "Generate peak file", I don't even need to drag the file into the timeline before it starts complaining. I have been dealing with this problem for over a day and am at my wits end, here is what I have tried and where I get it from:

- Placing files in the C drive instead of D drive suggested [here](https://adobe-video.uservoice.com/forums/911233-premiere-pro/suggestions/42537334-bug-frame-substitution-recursion-attempt-aborting)
- Disable Cuda and used "Software only" as the Playback and Rendering setting suggested [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5MkPQPefsYQ) and [here](https://community.adobe.com/t5/premiere-pro-discussions/warning-error-frame-substitution/td-p/10425018)
- Delete render files - this wasnt possible because it is greyed out but suggested [here](https://community.adobe.com/t5/premiere-pro-discussions/frame-substitution-recursion-attempt-aborting-after-multiple-attempts-on-file/td-p/10628534)

Additionally I changed my graphics card Drivers to Studio [Driver](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/drivers/) instead of Game-ready driver, this did not work either
[image: Latest version of the studio driver from Nvidia for my particular graphics card (Nvidia GeForce RTX 3080 ti)]

The next thing I can try is to reroll back to pre 14.4 [9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kk1iL.png) but I would really rather not have to do this.

==Edit==

I installed v 14.3 and got the same error so I installed 14.2 where i also got the same issue and then moved onto 14.1 where I am still getting the same issue. So this downgrade also is not working:

[image: As can been seen even in premiere pro 2020 v 4.1 I am getting the dreaded issue.]

I am really at a loss as to what to try next, any suggestions would be most welcome.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got this fixed, it turns out it was the plugin that came with 3.0.0 version of insta360 stitcher + updates.

Insta360 sent me their updated Stitcher 3.1.2 which comes with a brand new plugin but is not yet listed on their website. They have given me permission to post the file here for anyone who wishes to download it.

https://static.insta360.com/Insta360Stitcher/Insta360Stitcher_Winx64_3.1.2_build_202012301001.exe

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. I knew there were a newer Stitcher (btw, I'm using the 3.1.3), but it seems that even after installing the new Stitcher and marking "install the Premiere plugin", it doesn't work. I had to uninstall Premiere, uninstall Stitcher, install Premiere again, and directly install the last Stitcher to get it solved. Maybe just deleting the old plugin before is sufficient, I don't know. But thanks, your post make me think about a plugin conflict even with the last stitcher installed, and now everything is finally working :)